# Ubuntu control fan speed on multiple Nvidia GPUs

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, xorg

I have 3x Nvidia gpus, Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to be able to manually set GPU fan speeds.

When I create an xorg.conf file with the following:

```
Section "Device"
     Identifier      "Device0"
     Driver          "nvidia"
     VendorName      "NVIDIA"
     Option          "Coolbits" "4"
EndSection

Section "Device"
     Identifier      "Device1"
     Driver          "nvidia"
     VendorName      "NVIDIA"
     Option          "Coolbits" "4"
EndSection

Section "Device"
     Identifier      "Device2"
     Driver          "nvidia"
     VendorName      "NVIDIA"
     Option          "Coolbits" "4"
EndSection
```

Then reboot, then run:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1 -a [fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=80
```

This works fine. When I run:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:1]/GPUFanControlState=1 -a [fan:1]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=80
```

I get an error:

ERROR: Error assigning value 80 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' (this-box:0[fan:1]) as specified in assignment
       '[fan:1]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=80' (Unknown Error).

When I run:

```
nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus
nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=4
```

then reboot, I get a black creen with white cursor. I have tried multiple modifications to the xorg.conf generated by 2 lines above but havent been able to get past black screen with anything other than the basic xorg.conf at start of this post - which doesnt allow fan speed change on fan 1 or 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same config - 3 GPUs on 18.04.
Got it working by connecting a physical monitor to each of the 2 secondary GPUs in addition to the primary monitor and creating a new x screen for each of the two extra monitors from `X Server Display Configuration`.
Different ports on the same monitor would probably work too.

Screenshots of my nvidia settings:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rh2YnbK0VSPHH-JnSLLYUx7eCw7yQ2qG

Then I did `Save to X Configuration File -> Show Preview` and copied and pasted the contents to a text file and saved as `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.
Then I added `Option "Coolbits" "28"` line under `Section "Device"`for `Device0`, `Device1` and `Device2`.

This is what it looks like now:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 418.87.00

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "ViewSonic VT2430-M"
    HorizSync       15.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ GW2750H"
    HorizSync       0.0 - 0.0
    VertRefresh     0.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL ST2420L"
    HorizSync       0.0 - 0.0
    VertRefresh     0.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:67:0:0"
    Option "Coolbits" "28"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "TITAN Xp COLLECTORS EDITION"
    BusID          "PCI:10:0:0"
    Option "Coolbits" "28"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:66:0:0"
    Option "Coolbits" "28"

EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Restarted and Fan settings working on all GPUs:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XzSD-SOHLub57zlekiI9-zvypJklnQQW

Edit: got it working on another machine with 3 GPUs but with 16.04 without connecting extra physical monitors.
First ran `nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus`, then edited the xorg.conf file to add `Option "Coolbits" "28"` line under `Section "Device"`for `Device0`, `Device1` and `Device2` as before.
This is what it looks like:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 418.67


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2070"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Option "Coolbits" "28"  
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2070"
    BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
    Option "Coolbits" "28"    
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
    Option "Coolbits" "28"   
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Restarted and got fan settings working fine.

Not sure if it will work on 18.04 though. Don't want to mess up my config there so not trying it out on the 18.04 machine.